# Using a single CakePHP core for dev environment

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, mamp

I'm trying to get my CakePHP development environment set up just the way I like but I'm running into issues.

Here what my directory structure looks like

```
/dev/
    - vhosts/
        - app1/
        - app2/
        - app3/
    - lib/
        - cakephp/
        - otherlibs/
```

You get the idea, I want to be able to easily set up multiple CakePHP app running off one core located in an outside dir.

I've set the folowing values in webroot/index.php

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', '/dev');
}

if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', '/dev/vhosts/myapp');
}

define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '/dev/lib/cakephp/lib');
```

However when trying to access my app get a 500 error:

```
[Tue Sep 10 10:22:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I have two questions:

1. Can anyone steer me in the right direction for debugging this issue?
2. Can I expect (possibly with a bit of work) a setup where I can easily and automatically bake apps in my vhosts dir with all of these variables pre-set (possibly even creating the database on my dev server ^^)?

**EDIT:**
After a bit of tinkering I've narrowed the error down to my htaccess configuration.
It seems `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` does in fact need to point to the `lib/` dir inside the CakePHP installation (as per line 38 of `webroot/index.php`).

I can get to the Cake welcome page but there is no CSS since all assets are in webroot. So I add the following to htaccess as recomended by the Cake Docs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

At this point get the Error 500 which returns this in apache_error.log

```
[error] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[debug] r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /Volumes/Home/dev/vhosts/myapp/webroot/index.php
[debug] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
```

Comment: The constant APP_DIR has to be a directory name, not a path. In your case this is "myapp".

Comment: Thanks. And what's the purpose of ROOT?

Comment: It's the path to the directory that contains your app folder, as shown in the answer of @my3recipes.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths should be:

```
define('ROOT',  DS.'dev'.DS.'vhosts');
define('APP_DIR',   'app1');
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'dev'.DS.'lib'.DS.'cakephp');
```

Comment: What should CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH to point to exactly in the default CakePHP directory structure? The base dir ? lib/ ? or lib/Cake/ ?

Comment: Just cakephp path, no need to set sub-folders like lib/Cake

Comment: I've set my configuration like this but still getting Internal Server Error 500. Do you have any other ideas of what may cause this? I also tried this with no luck http://willcodeforcoffee.com/2007/01/31/cakephp-error-500-too-many-redirects/

Comment: Try to delete cache from /app/tmp. If it doesn't work, then search for other place

Comment: No that didnt work. I edited my original question with new info that might narrow down the problem.